# shuffle between activities without repetition Android game

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, random, shuffle

I have a game that has many different activities. It starts from a Main Menu and then Q1, Q2 and Q3 are 3 separate activities containing content. I know how to shuffle between activities but there is always repetition because I have about 30 activities. I've been searching and searching and finally decided to ask you guys. Read about bundles but couldn't figure it out on my own. I'm such a noob. Unless I can see the code i'm stuck. I tried by myself in many different ways but all of it is just nonsense I think. 
So basically when it shuffles it should go Q1 then Q3 then Q4.
Instead because It repeats it has the possibility of going Q1 then Q3 then Q1 again, which is disastrous for my game. Please help if possible with a little more detailed coding. I know i'm annoying, but I don't know any other programmers in my village.

MainMenu.java

```
    public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

final ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);

    activities.add(Q1.class);
    activities.add(Q2.class);
    activities.add(Q3.class);
}
public void onHintClick(View view) {

    Toast toasty = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.H1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toasty.show();

}






public void onAnswerClick(View v){


    if (activities.size()==0){
        activities.add(Q1.class);
        activities.add(Q2.class);
        activities.add(Q3.class);

    }
    Collections.shuffle(activities);

    Class activityToShow = activities.get(0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, activityToShow);
    activities.remove(0);
    startActivity(intent);
       }
    }
```

Q1.java

```
    public class Q1 extends AppCompatActivity {

final ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_q1);

    final ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<>();

    activities.add(Q2.class);
    activities.add(Q3.class);

}
    public void button(View view){


if (activities.size()==0){

    activities.add(Q2.class);
    activities.add(Q3.class);

}
Collections.shuffle(activities);

Class activityToShow = activities.get(0);

Intent intent = new Intent(Q1.this, activityToShow);
activities.remove(0);
startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

and similar code for Q2 and Q3.....what I need to know is, how to now make these pages repeat. Please tell me in the simplest way as I really am I noob.
Thanks in advance!

Android Manifest

```
        package="com.test.cross">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".MyApplication"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity android:name=".MainMenu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Q1" />
    <activity android:name=".Q2" />
    <activity android:name=".Q3">

    </activity>

   </application>


  </manifest>
```

My error

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.test.cross, PID: 2793
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                                at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                at com.test.cross.ActivityList.getRandomActivity(ActivityList.java:46)
                                                                                at com.test.cross.MainMenu.onAnswerClick(MainMenu.java:40)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the way I understand your post is, you don't want your activity to be re-created every time you get back to it?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I don't want my activities to keep repeating. I want them to start at random but not repeat the same activity twice until the end of the game where it goes back to the main menu again. hope you are able to understand.

Comment: I see. So every activity must only be gone through once? Why not just have a list or a set where the activities are, and then every time you start that activity, you can remove that activity from that list/set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain a list of activities that is common to all the activities, i.e. `ArrayList<Class> activities` should be common to Q1, Q2 and Q3. You can use the Application class to achieve the same by instantiating a singleton.

1. Application class -

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           ActivityList.init(30); // Pass number of activities here
       }
   }
   ```
2. Singleton -

   ```
   public class ActivityList {

       private static ActivityList instance;

       private final ArrayList<Class> activities;
       private final int numActivities;

       public static void init(int numActivities) {
           if (instance == null)
               instance = new ActivityList(numActivities);
       }

       private ActivityList(int numActivities) {
           this.numActivities = numActivities;
           activities = new ArrayList<>(numActivities);

           try {
               for(int i = 1 ; i <= numActivities ; i++) {
                   activities.add(Class.forName("com.test.cross.Q" + i));
               }
           } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
               ...
           }

           Collections.shuffle(activities);
       }

       public static ActivityList getInstance() {
           return instance;
       }

       public Class getRandomActivity() {
           if (activities.isEmpty()) {
               return MainMenu.class;
           }

           Class clazz = activities.get(0);
           activities.remove(0);

           return clazz;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Main menu -

   ```
   public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
       }

       public void onHintClick(View view) {
           Toast toasty = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.H1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toasty.show();
       }

       public void onAnswerClick(View v) {

           Class activityToShow = ActivityList.getInstance().getRandomActivity();

           Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, activityToShow);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Question classes -

   ```
   public class Q1 extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_q1);
       }

       public void button(View view) {

           Class activityToShow = ActivityList.getInstance().getRandomActivity();

           Intent intent = new Intent(Q1.this, activityToShow);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   }
   ```

In your manifest, you need to specify your Application class -

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication"
             android:allowBackup="true"....>
    <activity .....>
</application>
```

**EDIT 1:** Added a loop to (re)fill the list of activities, so in case you have multiple classes (Q1, Q2,...., Qn), you do not need to add all of them manually.

**EDIT 2:** Added `MainMenu` class.

Comment: hey...thanks for taking the time to reply...I feel really stupid for asking you this....but did you mean I need to make a class called MyApplication and ActivityList.....if so....when I copy and paste your code there is an error under init saying non static context...and under getRandomActivity in Q1.class and under "put" in Activitylist. I know its something i'm doing wrong...can you help?

Comment: @OldBeginner see my edited post, point 2 (singleton class). I forgot to add the static modifiers. And yes, you need to create the `MyApplication` and `ActivityList` classes. Also, you need to add the fully qualified name of `MyApplication` to your manifests application tag.

Comment: @OldBeginner I messed up the singleton pattern, my bad. It's fixed now, please take a look at the code again.

Comment: Hey Rohan....i'm still getting an error in "put" in the activitylist class....it says cannot resolve method "put"

Comment: It's `ArrayList.add()`, not put...my mistake once again. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: I made it "add" and it says null point exception error for the line  in mainmenu.class ....Is it to do with theManifest....I added it like this                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      <activity android:name="MyApplication"></activity>                                                       is it wrong?.....please don't give up on me yet :)

Comment: Class activityToShow = ActivityList.getInstance().getRandomActivity(); this is the error line

Comment: Yes, you've incorrectly added your Application class to the manifest. There will already be an `<application>` tag in your manifest, just put `android:name=".MyApplication"` inside it. Do not create a new `<activity>` tag. See the last part of my post

Comment: Class clazz = activities.get(0); have error here and the class activity show is also still showing error....sorry rohan

Comment: almost there...please don't give up on me :)

Comment: hey rohan...I have added the manifest...is it working for you when you try it?...if yes just let me know...I will keep trying different ways...I suck at this man...sheesh

Comment: I think I found the problem. In the call to `Class.forName()`, give the fully qualified name of Q1, Q2 etc....Example: `Class.forName("com.test.cross.Q" + i)`. I do not have access to an IDE now, otherwise would have checked and let you know.

Comment: wow rohan you are bloody awesome !....thanks for taking the time ... I just have 1 more doubt....I accepted the answer because you answered exactly what I needed ...I forgot to ask one more thing....after the 3 Q's are over I want it to return to mainmenu....can you tell me the code I have to add in each page for that?....thanks again for your time.

Comment: Just move the part where yo populate the list to the constructor. updated singleton code, check it out.

Comment: hey rohan....now it directly goes to the mainmenu when I press any button in Q1, Q2 or Q3....its like the activities are empty by the time I answer the first question...it also says Numactivities is never accessed in the singleton page...

Comment: hey rohan...its working now...thanks again...the error was happening when I tried it in my game code when I purely try it with the codes you provide it works fine(although the numActivity not accessed notification is still there)........thanks a lot for taking the time to guide me...at least now I know the way to do it...need to figure out how to use it with my code now...my respect for programmers have increased twofolds ever since I've started attempting programming...haha...

Comment: hey rohan...if you don't mind I have one more question...I have android:nohistory set as true in the manifest for all my Q's because I get an out of memory error otherwise....but because of that when the game finishes the first time all the activities are erased so I can't play the game a second time unless I exit the game completely and start again..this started happening after I started using the singleton code...any solution to this?...if you don't mind....and this will be my last question I swear :)

Comment: As for `numActivities`, you can safely get rid of the global one in the singleton. It's not really needed. Instead of using `android:nohistory`, make a call to `finish()` from the `onPause()` method of each of your Q's and see how that works out for you.

Comment: hey rohan...it doesn't help....is there anything I can change in your code that will help me?....or is this something I have to deal with if I want to randomize activities :)...appreciate all the help

Comment: Remove the `instance == null` check from `ActivityList.init()`, get rid of the custom application class and just make a call to init from your main menu activity. I'm not going to provide any more code now, it's pretty straightforward you can figure it out.